# How to view a webpage stored in sdcard in Android browser

Tags: android, android-browser

I am trying to view a webpage stored in sdcard directly in the browser in an emulator.

I know I can copy the webpage in the assets folder and use a webview to load it.

But is there a way this be done directly? (equivalent of typing "c:\mywebpage.html" in Internet Explorer on a PC)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this 
file:///sdcard/pathToPAge
or /sdcard/pathToPAge

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. The first option works perfectly on my emulator.